# Is there functionality in the akka-Kafka (scala framework) to list all available topics

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream, akka-kafka

I am trying to check if a topic passed to my "start stream" method is a valid/already existing topic in the Kafka that my program is connected to.

I know Java has the KafkaConsumer.ListTopics, but I'm working with the akka-kafka library and it seems the ConsumerSetting doesn't have the same method. I could have code that executes a script to list the kafka topics using the Kafka-topics --list command, but I would prefer a less janky way than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to [create the `KafkaConsumer`](https://doc.akka.io/api/alpakka-kafka/1.0.3/akka/kafka/ConsumerSettings$.html#createKafkaConsumer[K,V](settings:akka.kafka.ConsumerSettings[K,V]):org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer[K,V]) from that Settings object, then you can use the API methods you mentioned.

You should not expose Zookeeper directly to unauthenticated clients.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for that is by getting the topics list from zookeeper, like this:

```
 import org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper;

 val zk = new ZooKeeper("localhost:2181", 10000, null)
 val topics = zk.getChildren("/brokers/topics", false)
```